# show background color for active class

Tags: html, css, background-color

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MZ9wa/)

I have posted my full codes on jsfiddle.

I want this -> if `.panel #Default a .active` show different background color for `.vehicle_details` class

I have tried this code

```
.panel #Default a .active:.vehicle_details
{
    background: #000000;
}
```

but its not working. See my jsfiddle link

Comment: Some pretty messed by HTML structure there too. You have links in links unclosed spans etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no `a` elements with `.active` class in your fiddle, so I assume that you are talking about the `span`s.

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS. I would apply the `.active` class straight to the `.vehicle_details` element. Otherwise you cannot do that via CSS.

Comment: applying the `active` class to the `.vehicle_details` is the correct way.

Comment: why did you use id instead of class for `active`?

Comment: i have already used another class (vehicle_details). so only i used id

Comment: You can have as many classes as you want. `class="vehicle-details active"`. And in css `.vehicle_details.active {}`